# android studio update R when layout changed

Tags: android-studio, android-resources, r.java-file

I need help to understand how to make `R` updating after I change my layout. In eclipse when you set the build automatically option, when you change your layout (eg: you add a new view with id `@+id/new_id`) and then you go to the Activity editor, I can immediately see `new_id` in the intellisense options when I type `R.id.`

In android studio I can't find a way to obtain the same behaviour, which I find much usefull

Here is my build settings screen

[image]

thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pascal: people sometimes use the `[r]` tag when they should use the `[r.java-file]` tag. Just make (or suggest) the edit.

Comment: sorry for a wrong usage of "r" tag, I didn't knew it